# How to separate last three numbers and a string from the rest of the text in excel

Tags: excel, split

I have:

> Column 1

```
Here is line one abc 1 3 100
Here is another line jkmr 5-20 230 3
Other line three rjleer 44 10 22
```

and want to turn it into:

[image]

So far I have this:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(C1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-3)))
```

that separates the last four strings. Then I can separate them on spaces. But how can I remove these last four strings from from the text?

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: Where did the `3` in E2 come from?

Comment: Sorry missed to include it. Edited the post.

Comment: so split on the space and take the Ubound(array)-3 for the first and -2 for the second, -1 for the third and the ubound for the last.

Comment: Ubound? What is it? Is there a built-in excel function to do it? I can split by the space using DATA/Text to Column.

Comment: ubound is vba, you did not specify formulas.

Comment: I have only this: =RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(C1," ","*",LEN(C1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C1," ",""))-3)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to give you the desired result:

```
Sub BreakUp()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, k As Long, j As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        k = 0
        arr = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")

        For j = 6 To 3 Step -1
            Cells(i, j).Value = arr(UBound(arr) - k)
            k = k + 1
        Next j

        For j = 0 To UBound(arr) - 4
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & arr(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    End Sub
```